# Laravel eloquent one()->ofMany() for "next or last" item?

Tags: laravel

I have a model Schedule with publication dates for an item e.g. Movie: a movie can be scheduled 0 or more times.

I want to know: 1) when is the next schedule or if there is no next schedule 2) when was the last time the movie was scheduled?

For Movie I have relations like:

```
    public function lastScheduleEvent(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->scheduleEvents()->one()->ofMany('starts_at','max');
    }

    public function nextScheduleEvent(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->scheduleEvents()->one()->ofMany([
            'starts_at' => 'max'
        ], function (Builder $query) {
            $query->where('starts_at','>',now());
        }
        );
    }
```

And an attribute to get the last or next schedule:

```
    protected function nextOrLastScheduleEvent(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::make(
            get: fn ($value) => $this->nextScheduleEvent ?? $this->lastScheduleEvent
        );
    }
```

Can I create an `one()->ofMany(...)` relationship (instead of an attribute) to get the `nextOrLastScheduleEvent`?

I.e. is there a query that can be used with a min/max aggregator to get the next or last schedule event?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can create a single relationship to get the next or last scheduled event. You can use a custom SQL expression and one()->ofMany(...) relationship.

```
public function nextOrLastScheduleEvent(): HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(ScheduleEvent::class)
        ->ofMany([
            'priority' => 'min',
        ], function (Builder $query) {
            $query->selectRaw('CASE WHEN starts_at > NOW() THEN 1 ELSE 2 END as priority')
                ->orderBy('starts_at', 'DESC');
        });
}
```

This code will first check if the event is in the future or in the past. It will give priority to future events. If there are no future events, it will choose the most recent past event. This way, you can get the next or last scheduled event in one relationship.

Comment: Nice! And I assume you also want to add 'starts_at' => 'min' after 'priority' => 'min' to make sure the earliest schedule event is picked.

Comment: It gives an error message that column priority is not known.